# VBA WebScraping a website that requires sendkeys

Tags: vba, sendkeys

I need to webscrape a website that I actually have to type the keys to show the password form.

I've tried this code with no success (even using the right login)

```
Sub login()

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True


IE.navigate ("https://wsvr10.coamo.com.br/npl/#!/login")

While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Wend
sng = Timer
Do While sng + 5 > Timer
Loop

Dim idoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set idoc = IE.document

idoc.all.cpf.Value = "11111111111"
```

Comment: Go back and read what you wrote....would you be able to answer that.....redo the question and be as detailed as possible.  Show all relevant code.  You state sendkeys yet I do not see anywhere in the code sample you provided...sendkeys

Comment: Please write the code correctly. And what result did you get?

Comment: @Sorceri sorry english is not my native language and I didn't express the problem. The code above runs well and the numbers appear on the form, but it doesnt show a password form, but if i manually type the numbers the password form appears. So i guess the answer to be able to login to this website using vba would be sendkeys, but I don't know how to use it. I'm trying to find a better way, and also doing some research on sendkeys but with no success...

Comment: ie.document.all("cpf").Focus
SendKeys "11111"